# How to filtered the duplicate values and get most recent transaction object using JS filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

With below code i was able to get duplicate but i am trying to get most recent object from each drug by using `transactionDate` property,Below code is only filtering duplicates any idea how to get most recent transaction for each drug.

main.js

```
var drugsArray =  [{
  drugName: "ADVIL",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-15"
},{
  drugName: "ADVIL",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-28"
}, 
 {
  drugName: "ATRIPLA",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-05"
},{
  drugName: "ATRIPLA",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-21"
}

];

function getDrugs(data) {

 let filtered = data.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (! accumulator.find(({drugName}) => drugName === current.drugName)) {
    var checkRecentDate = getLatestDateSave(current.transactionDate)
    if(checkRecentDate) {
      accumulator.push(current);
    }

  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

  console.log(filtered);
}


getDrugs(drugsArray);
```

get the recent date object using this function

```
function getLatestDateSave(xs) {
   if (xs.length) {
      return xs.reduce(function(m, i) {
         return (i.MeasureDate > m) && i || m;
      }, "").MeasureDate;
   }
 }
```

Expected output is

```
result = [{
        drugName: "ADVIL",
        transactionDate: "2018-12-28"
    },
    {
        drugName: "ATRIPLA",
        transactionDate: "2018-12-21"
    }

];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approach this with [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method. Also, with the format you use on the dates, they can be compared direcly as strings. Example:

```js
var drugsArray =  [
    {drugName: "ADVIL", transactionDate: "2018-12-15"},
    {drugName: "ADVIL", transactionDate: "2018-12-28"},
    {drugName: "ATRIPLA", transactionDate: "2018-12-05"},
    {drugName: "ATRIPLA", transactionDate: "2018-12-21"}
];

let result = drugsArray.reduce((res, curr) =>
{
    let exists = res.findIndex(x => x.drugName === curr.drugName);

    if (exists < 0)
        res.push(curr);
    else if (res[exists].transactionDate < curr.transactionDate)
        res[exists].transactionDate = curr.transactionDate;

    return res;
        
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfeclty, when you get a chance please also explain what this code is doing i didnt quite understand reduce method

Comment: There is a link to documentation, I thinked you already know it because is used on your question. But basically the reduce iterates over all elements of the array while generating an accumulator. The accumulator start with the empty array `[]`. On every iteration it checks if the current element of the iteration already exists on the accumulated array, if element don't exists, we push it on the array, but if element exists, we compares the dates and update if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can first group the transactions into an object of arrays, then sort the dates in descending order and pick the first one:

```js
const drugsArray = [{
    drugName: "ADVIL",
    transactionDate: "2018-12-15"
  }, {
    drugName: "ADVIL",
    transactionDate: "2018-12-28"
  },
  {
    drugName: "ATRIPLA",
    transactionDate: "2018-12-05"
  }, {
    drugName: "ATRIPLA",
    transactionDate: "2018-12-21"
  }
];

// First group the transactions into an object of arrays
const transactionMap = {};
for (const obj of drugsArray) {
  const key = obj.drugName;
  if (!transactionMap[key]) {
    transactionMap[key] = [];
  }
  transactionMap[key].push(obj);
}

// Then sort each group by transaction date and pick the first one
const result = [];
for (const obj in transactionMap) {
  transactionMap[obj].sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(b.transactionDate) - new Date(a.transactionDate);
  });
  result.push(transactionMap[obj][0]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is an effective approach, but you must ensure that data is ordered by `transactionDate`. Maybe you could add a `sort()` step at initialization just to ensure this pre-condition.

Comment: @Shidersz Thanks for picking that up. I ended up grouping the transactions, then sorting to get the most recent date. Although its not very efficient since you need to sort to get the max date.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was sort the array by transaction date and then by name. Then I took the duplicate filter method in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript), which filters out the first item found in a duplicate set.

```js
var drugsArray =  [{
  drugName: "ADVIL",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-15"
},{
  drugName: "ADVIL",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-28"
}, 
{
  drugName: "ATRIPLA",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-05"
},{
  drugName: "ATRIPLA",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-21"
},
{
  drugName: "AMBIEN",
  transactionDate: "2018-02-05"
},{
  drugName: "AMBIEN",
  transactionDate: "2018-12-06"
}

];

function getDrugs(){
    const output = drugsArray
    .sort(function(d1, d2){
      return new Date(d1.transactionDate) < new Date(d2.transactionDate) ? 1 : -1;
    })
    .sort(function(d1, d2){
      return d1.drugName < d2.drugName ? -1 : 1;
    })
    .filter(function(value, index, self) { 
        return index === self.findIndex(function(i){
          return i.drugName === value.drugName
        })
    });
    
    return output;
}

console.log(getDrugs());
```

Now this only evaluates the dates as strings. You can implicitly convert the date strings to Date objects first before comparing.

Comment: this is not returning most recent dated object it returns earlier dates

Comment: @hussain 12-28 is more recent than 12-15, and then the rest are more recent. Look at it more closely.

Comment: your sniipet is returning `[
  {
    "drugName": "ADVIL",
    "transactionDate": "2018-12-15"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "AMBIEN",
    "transactionDate": "2018-02-05"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "ATRIPLA",
    "transactionDate": "2018-12-05"
  }
]`

Comment: It's returning `[
  {
    "drugName": "ADVIL",
    "transactionDate": "2018-12-28"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "AMBIEN",
    "transactionDate": "2018-12-06"
  },
  {
    "drugName": "ATRIPLA",
    "transactionDate": "2018-12-21"
  }
]`

for me what the hell. If that's the case we need to convert the strings to dates first which would take a minute. There's probably a browser issue going on

Comment: I just tried here on stackOverflow and pasted the result

Comment: @hussain I converted it to a Date object. But older browsers might not support this string date formatting passed as a parameter in a Date object. You need to make a cross-browser compatible version.